# Area51 commit-limit does not make sense

Tags: feature-request, area-51, commitment

I'm new to Area51. I found on virtually the first page 3 topics that I'm interested in and want to participate in, so I commited to them ... and then I went to some more pages and found more topics ... and get told I cannot support these topics because of some arbitrary limit of three commitments.

Please remove this limit and let the actual participation decide the issue.

(Why not just put the sites up, monitor their performance periodically, and after some cut-off period decide their fate)

[Mark Robinson asked the same question previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66279/remove-maximum-number-of-proposal-commits-in-area-51) - more pertinent answers there.

Comment: Actually I don't know how people can handle more than one commitment at a time...

Comment: Some people have a varied interest and do not obsessively focus on just one thing ;)

Comment: you can always follow a proposal by clicking on the definition tab and then choosing "follow". Save your commitments for the three closest-to-100% sites. You'll get your commitment token back after having participated a bit and then you can commit to the next site. The limit is intended to make sure people do not over-commit and then lack the time to help all sites at once, although that may be a bit over-parenting...

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66279/remove-maximum-number-of-proposal-commits-in-area-51 (my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [progress tab](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress) at Area 51. On (eye-estimated) average, there are usually 2-3 between beta launches, and increasing distance recently. So it is likely that one of your three commitments is fulfilled before another site you'd like to commit to reaches beta. Just stick to the top three ones and only follow the others for now.

Comment: Is there a way I can take back a commit so I can use it on another topic?

Comment: @slashmais: sure, go to the proposals site and the "commit" button is turned into an "uncommit" button when you are currently committed. But consider a commitment more serious than following - it means "I will *actively* participate this site and will visit it several time per week". Also you shouldn't uncommit too often

Comment: I like your idea for a workaround but it should not be necessary. I think this apparently arbitrary limit should be removed.