# Current limit of 3 commitments is inadequate?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove maximum number of proposal commits in Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66279/remove-maximum-number-of-proposal-commits-in-area-51)

The point of commitment is to guarantee that there's enough user mass for proper seeding of a community with insightful questions, that's why commitments are fulfilled within 10 days of the beta launch.

At the moment I am willing to perform commitments on a rather broad set of sites, not only because I am ready to bring insightful questions and answers, but also because I want to see the SE promoted to the beta phase. Some SE progress, however, is sluggish, so I had to withdraw my commitment from some of them in order to push forward others, despite the fact that I have full intention to provide commitment on all of them. This falsifies the actual interest, as I have to withdraw a commitment to a site, pushing it backward, a commitment I want to give anyway.

Am I the only one finding the current limit of 3 commitments inadequate, now that the throughput for new SE is much, much slower than at the beginning ?

Comment: I think the only reason why there put the limit on is to stop people making hundress of accounts and commiting to them all.

Comment: @Benny: that would not change, you can make n*hundreds and commit them all anyway, and their contribute would be negligible. It's reputation that counts in commitment phase, and a new user's reputation is 1.

Comment: But on Area 51 you need at least 50 rep to commit to it and that can change by simply confirming your email

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove maximum number of proposal commits in Area 51](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66279/remove-maximum-number-of-proposal-commits-in-area-51) I actually had to go to google to dig that one up...

Comment: duplicate. voting to close as well.